# Formatação de JSON com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, json

Precisava formatar um JSON, e transformar ele em uma string, um exemplo mais ou menos do que eu queria, foi isso que eu consegui escrever com python, porém eu precisava disso em JavaScript para poder colocar no meu aplicativo:

O JSON:

```
{'COLUNA1': 'DADO', 'COLUNA2': 'DADO', 'COLUNA': [{'COLUNA1': 'DADO', 'COLUNA2': 'DADO', 'COLUNA3': 'DADO', 'COLUNA4': 'DADO', 'COLUNA5': 'DADO', 'COLUNA6': 'DADO', 'COLUNA7': 'DADO', 'COLUNA8': 'DADO', 'COLUNA9': 'DADO', 'COLUNA10': 'DADO', 'COLUNA11': 'DADO', 'COLUNA12': 'DADO', 'COLUNA13': 'DADO'}], 'COLUNA14': 'DADO', 'COLUNA15': 'DADO', 'COLUNA16': 'DADO', 'COLUNA17': 'DADO', 'COLUNA18': 'DADO', 'COLUNA19': 'DADO', 'COLUNA20': 'DADO', 'COLUNA21': 'DADO', 'COLUNA22': 'DADO', 'COLUNA23': 'DADO', 'COLUNA24': 'DADO', 'COLUNA25': 'DADO', 'COLUNA26': 'DADO', 'COLUNA27': 'DADO', 'COLUNA28': 'DADO', 'COLUNA29': 'DADO', 'COLUNA30': 'DADO', 'COLUNA31': 'DADO', 'COLUNA32': 'DADO', 'COLUNA33': 'DADO', 'COLUNA34': 'DADO', 'COLUNA35': 'DADO', 'COLUNA36': [{'COLUNA1': 'DADO', 'COLUNA2': 'DADO'}, {'COLUNA1': 'DADO', 'COLUNA2': 'DADO'}, {'COLUNA1': 'DADO', 'COLUNA2': 'DADO'}, {'COLUNA1': 'DADO', 'COLUNA2': 'DADO'}], 'COLUNA37': 'DADO', 'COLUNA38': 'DADO', 'COLUNA39': 'DADO', 'COLUNA40': 'DADO', 'COLUNA41': 'DADO', 'COLUNA42': 'DADO', 'COLUNA43': 'DADO', 'COLUNA44': 'DADO', 'COLUNA45': 'DADO', 'COLUNA46': 'DADO', 'COLUNA47': 'DADO', 'COLUNA48': 'DADO', 'COLUNA49': 'DADO', 'COLUNA50': 'DADO', 'COLUNA51': 'DADO', 'COLUNA52': 'DADO', 'COLUNA53': 'DADO', 'COLUNA54': 'DADO', 'COLUNA55': 'DADO', 'COLUNA56': 'DADO', 'COLUNA57': 'DADO', 'COLUNA58': 'DADO'}
```

E isso embaixo seria o resultado que eu queria, que foi o que eu consegui chegar usando o python.

```
COLUNA1: DADO
COLUNA2: DADO
COLUNA:
  COLUNA1: DADO
  COLUNA2: DADO
  COLUNA3: DADO
  COLUNA4: DADO
  COLUNA5: DADO
  COLUNA6: DADO
  COLUNA7: DADO
  COLUNA8: DADO
  COLUNA9: DADO
  COLUNA10: DADO
  COLUNA11: DADO
  COLUNA12: DADO
  COLUNA13: DADO
COLUNA14: DADO
COLUNA15: DADO
COLUNA16: DADO
COLUNA17: DADO
COLUNA18: DADO
COLUNA19: DADO
COLUNA20: DADO
COLUNA21: DADO
COLUNA22: DADO
COLUNA23: DADO
COLUNA24: DADO
COLUNA25: DADO
COLUNA26: DADO
COLUNA27: DADO
COLUNA28: DADO
COLUNA29: DADO
COLUNA30: DADO
COLUNA31: DADO
COLUNA32: DADO
COLUNA33: DADO
COLUNA34: DADO
COLUNA35: DADO
COLUNA36:
  COLUNA1: DADO
  COLUNA2: DADO
  COLUNA1: DADO
  COLUNA2: DADO
  COLUNA1: DADO
  COLUNA2: DADO
  COLUNA1: DADO
  COLUNA2: DADO
COLUNA37: DADO
COLUNA38: DADO
COLUNA39: DADO
COLUNA40: DADO
COLUNA41: DADO
COLUNA42: DADO
COLUNA43: DADO
COLUNA44: DADO
COLUNA45: DADO
COLUNA46: DADO
COLUNA47: DADO
COLUNA48: DADO
COLUNA49: DADO
COLUNA50: DADO
COLUNA51: DADO
COLUNA52: DADO
COLUNA53: DADO
COLUNA54: DADO
COLUNA55: DADO
COLUNA56: DADO
COLUNA57: DADO
COLUNA58: DADO
```

Esse é o meu código python:

```
import json

def formatJSON(data):
    result = ""
    for key, value in data.items():
        key = key.replace("_", " ").upper()
        if isinstance(value, list):
            result += f"{key}:\n"
            for item in value:
                for subkey, subvalue in item.items():
                    subkey = subkey.replace("_", " ").upper()
                    subvalue = "Sim" if subvalue is True else subvalue
                    subvalue = "Não" if subvalue is False else subvalue
                    subvalue = "Sem informações" if subvalue in [None, ""] else subvalue
                    result += f"  {subkey}: {subvalue}\n"
        else:
            value = "Sim" if value is True else value
            value = "Não" if value is False else value
            value = "Sem informações" if value in [None, ""] else value
            result += f"{key}: {value}\n"
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("data.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
        
    print(formatJSON(data))
```

Preciso muito de um formato desse mesmo código só que em Javascript.

Comment: Importante, sempre que postar uma pergunta que envolva código, fornecer  um [mcve] do problema que esbarrou ao tentar resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Fiz esse código a um tempo atrás, a formatação do Json precisava ser parecida, atualizei o código para ficar no formato que você precisa, veja se funciona.

```js
function formatJSON(data) {
    let result = "";
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        const formattedKey = key.replace("_", " ").toUpperCase();
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            result += `${formattedKey}:\n`;
            for (const item of value) {
                for (const [subkey, subvalue] of Object.entries(item)) {
                    const formattedSubkey = subkey.replace("_", " ").toUpperCase();
                    let formattedSubvalue = subvalue;
                    if (subvalue === true) {
                        formattedSubvalue = "Sim";
                    } else if (subvalue === false) {
                        formattedSubvalue = "Não";
                    } else if (subvalue === null || subvalue === "") {
                        formattedSubvalue = "Sem informações";
                    }
                    result += `  ${formattedSubkey}: ${formattedSubvalue}\n`;
                }
            }
        } else {
            let formattedValue = value;
            if (value === true) {
                formattedValue = "Sim";
            } else if (value === false) {
                formattedValue = "Não";
            } else if (value === null || value === "") {
                formattedValue = "Sem informações";
            }
            result += `${formattedKey}: ${formattedValue}\n`;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sou novo no Stackoverflow, porque minha resposta teve um voto negativo?

Comment: Tudo que acham "Irrelevante" fazem isso... O Stack em Português é ruim por isso, as pessoas só saem dando -1 para os outros... Muito obrigado pela ajuda, me ajudou demais amigo

Comment: @GabrielGarcia Valeu, bom saber, de nada cara, conhecimento é pra ser compartilhado.

Comment: Não tenho como responder por outros votantes, mas uma característica da postagem aqui é que ela basicamente só serve para resolver o problema do @GabrielGarcia se for mantida desta forma, e esse tipo de postagem é desincentivado por não cumprir bem o objetvo do site, que é de compor um repositório útil para vistantes futuros. Para isto, a pergunta antes teria que ser melhorada conforme orientações dadas no fechamento, para que seja possível uma resposta fácil de ser entendida e reaproveitada em diversas situações.

Comment: Lembrando ainda que geralmente isso se resolve com edições estratégicas para que a postagem vire referência canônica, tanto é que os fechamentos desse tipo vem com instruções (inclusive, bem detalhadas) de como melhorar a postagem - justamente para que ela possa ser reaberta.